# How to resolve RangeError: Invalid time value

Tags: reactjs, utc, daterangepicker

Making use of React, I have set up a DatePicker component using moment and react-datepicker library and am passing it an initial date value calculated using today's date in the MM-DD-YYYY format.

When I try to load I get this error line :

> throw new RangeError('Invalid time value');
>      Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone.This ensures that when UTC functions will be implemented, locales will be compatible with them.`

DatePicker component:

```
class DatePicker extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // <input type="date" 
      //   className={this.props.className + " myInput"} 
      //   placeholder={this.props.placeholder} 
      //   onChange={this.props.onChange} 
      //   value={this.props.value}
      // />
        <DatePicker2
          dateFormat="DD MMM YYYY"
          className={this.props.className + " myInput"} 
          selected={moment(this.props.value)}
          onChange={this.props.onChange} 
          readOnly={true}
        />
    );
  }
}

export default DatePicker;
```

My question is: how do I Convert the date in system timezone to the same date in UTC+00:00 timezone (assuming that's the solution, but if not, how do I resolve this?

Comment: what format is this.props.value in?

Answer (score 1):

To reformat the date you can use:

`moment(this.props.value).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z");`